# Can't interact with chrome extension page with playwright

Tags: playwright

I want to automate metamask chrome extension with playwright. I found the code below in the API document. I'm able to load Metemask extension but when I try to click the Get Started button on the metamask home page it shows timeout error waiting for the selector.

I need help to check what is the problem and how to work with backgroundpage

```
(async () => {
  const pathToExtension = require('path').join(__dirname, 'my-extension');
  const userDataDir = '/tmp/test-user-data-dir';
  const browserContext = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(userDataDir,{
    headless: false,
    args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
      `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`
    ]
  });
  const backgroundPage = browserContext.backgroundPages()[0];
  // Test the background page as you would any other page.
  await backgroundPage.click('.btn-primary') // Get Started button

  await browserContext.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Background page is invisible and doesn't have the button you are trying to click. What you need is to be able to click on elements inside the extension popup window which is currently not supported. Please thumb up this feature request https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5593 if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is long and complicated as question is kinda general.

Metamask with playwright is supported with synpress (out-of-the-box).

You can find your answer in its codebase, [in this place](https://github.com/drptbl/synpress-examples/blob/master/playwright/isolated-state/fixtures.ts).

[Synpress](https://github.com/Synthetixio/synpress) is e2e testing framework based on [Cypress](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress) and [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) with support for [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/).

Check below for more examples of usage with playwright:
https://github.com/drptbl/synpress-examples